# Printing characters on different lines into a string in Python 3.8

Tags: python, git

Here's my code, at the moment it prints the decrypted Caesar Cypher characters all on seperate lines. Is there any way to add them onto one line as a string ? Moreover is there a possible way to implement .isalpha() to account for spaces and questions marks etc in the uncrypted message.

```
"""Cypher program."""
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
message = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"
key = 7
for char in message:
    new_char = key + (alphabet.index(char))
    if new_char > 25:
        new_char = new_char % 26
    print(alphabet[new_char])
```

I am quite new to Python, very sorry if this is a newbie question.

Many thanks to whomever is kind enough to help.

Comment: string.isalnum() -> is a build in str . But do you want to check if is alpha or to remove other chars?

Comment: I would like to add the other characters that are not in the alphabet in an unchanged form into the endstring, so a space would remain a space after the decryption and a dot would remain a dot etc.

Comment: i understand.. i will modify my answer to include that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append alphabet[new_char] into a list and then use join to print it as string. Sample code below (edited to let chars that are not alpha numeric to be left in place):

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
message = "the quick brow???nxa2 fox jumps over the lazy dog"
key = 7
lst=[]
for char in message:
    if char.isalpha() is True:
        new_char = key + (alphabet.index(char))
        if new_char > 25:
            new_char = new_char % 26
        lst.append(alphabet[new_char])
    else:
        lst.append(char)
print(''.join(i for i in lst))
```

Comment: God bless you good sir! Is there any way to perhaps add spaces and periods into the string at the end if this   `message = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."` would be instead of `message = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"`

Comment: @Homer oopss.. aparentetly i edited your post :( sorry

Comment: Fixed ... (even if it's in approval)
Also you solution doesn't keep count of other chars ( ? | ! and so on)

Comment: Thanks @user2099394 , just updated my code to include special characters

Comment: Thanks for this, I intended to use .isalpha() to define if a character in a sentence is not in the alphabet, in other words is there a way to implement isalpha() so i don't have to use multiple if statements for every different punctuation mark that could be in a regular sentence, for example `.,?'!"#¤%&/(`

Answer (score 0):

```
"""Cypher program."""
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
message = "thequick0brownfox jumpsoverthelazydog"

def transform(char,key):
    if char.isalpha():
       new_char = key + (alphabet.index(char))
       if new_char > 25:
           new_char = new_char % 26
       return alphabet[new_char]
    return char

key = 7

# faster string comprehension
decripted = [transform(char,key) for char in message]
  
print(decripted)
# or 

# "".join - puts all elements of an array toghether in a string using a separator
print("".join(decripted))
```